# Trying to filter out zero frequency components with a low pass filter

Tags: filtering

```
seq = Rescale[
Table[SawtoothWave[n/16.], {n, 0, 255}] + 
RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 256]];
GraphicsRow[{Periodogram[seq, PlotRange -> All], 

GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot /@ {seq, LowpassFilter[seq, .5]}] Spectrogram[seq, 128, 32]}]
```

My understanding is that I am running seq through a lowpass filter [.5]

Comment: how could one remove the zero frequency (DC) using low pass filter? The whole idea of low pass filter, is that it allows low frequencies to go through and blocks the high frequencies. Zero frequency is as low as it gets. I am not following the title of the question. (did not try your code btw). Did you mean to use highpass filter?

Comment: Why do you think it is called low-*PASS*?